# Metamask does not show balance of account on private Ethereum network

Tags: ethereum, metamask, go-ethereum

I have setup a local network with geth, the nodes have discovered one another and I am able to send transactions
I connected metamask from browser to the default http rpc port 8545, created new account in the metamask
Sending transaction to the newly connected account works, I am able to see the correct balances in the JS console

> eth.sendTransaction({to: '0x167f42B8b6d4666ecf2Dbd2D7Dd767Bb617C339A',
> from: eth.accounts[0],value: 5});
> "0xda56eea22623e827e66e3155f8dcdcebca97a35553d89ad8fdd9310c1b88151e"
>
> eth.getBalance("0x167f42B8b6d4666ecf2Dbd2D7Dd767Bb617C339A")
>
> 5

But the metamask wallet still shows 0 ETH as balance for the account 0x167f42B8b6d4666ecf2Dbd2D7Dd767Bb617C339A

I have added the network in metamask as below:

New RPC URL: http://localhost:8545

Chain ID: 59999

Currency symbol: ETH

telnet to localhost 8545 works.
How should I troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: 1) Possible rounding issue. The value `5` suggests 5 wei - not 5 ETH. MetaMask might round this value down to 0 ETH in their UI... 2) MetaMask requests data from the node using the JSON RPC API, possibly querying the balance using the `eth` namespace of the API. Check if your API enables the `eth` namespace (or possibly others that might be required) ... 3) Actually, check if the API is reachable from the browser.

Comment: Thanks, it was rounding issue, sending value in ETH did show the balance in Metamask.